# C++ code to read HEVC video and extract frames

Tags: c++, hevc

Could any one help me how to read HEVC video and extract frames using c++.

I tried using matlab , but matlab cannot read HEVC videos.

Can anyone help me how to read HEVC videos using C++ in windows 7 and extract frames, so that I can perform some operation on these frames.

Simple c++ code or  logic.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using FFMPEG. It's OpenSource and trivial to use.

You find a copy&paste example here:
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/api-example_8c-source.html

What you want is shown in the function:

```
static void video_decode_example(const char *outfilename, const char *filename) {
```

Instead of `pgm_save` you would finally call `sws_scale` or use the raw frames directly. But normally you want to map them back from YUV to RGB.

Please note that use of HVEC as well as H264 might incur a license fee of 5 mio. US dollars depending on your use-case. The 5 mio. are for H264 but I think HVEC has something similar (or will get it soon, so be aware).